# How can I use Mockito.doThrow in a micronaut test to simulate exceptions thrown by a service call?

Tags: unit-testing, mockito, micronaut

I want to simulate a few possible exceptions thrown during a service method call. I wrote the following micronaut test (I am using micronaut 1.1.2 
):

```
@MicronautTest
public class HelloWorldControllerTest {

   @Inject
   private AcmeService acmeService;
   @Inject
   @Client("/")
   private RxHttpClient client;

   @MockBean(AcmeService.class)
   public AcmeService acmeService() {
      return Mockito.mock(AcmeService.class);
   }

   @Test
   public void test_without_exception() {

      HttpResponse httpResponse = client.toBlocking().exchange(HttpRequest.GET("/"));
      Assertions.assertEquals(HttpStatus.OK, httpResponse.getStatus());
   }

   @Test
   public void test_with_nullpointer_exception() {

      Mockito.doThrow(new NullPointerException("nullpointer"))
            .when(acmeService)
            .doSomething(Mockito.anyString());

      HttpClientResponseException responseException = Assertions.assertThrows(HttpClientResponseException.class,
            () -> client.toBlocking().exchange(HttpRequest.GET("/")));

      Assertions.assertEquals("Internal Server Error: nullpointer", responseException.getMessage());
   }

   @Test
   public void test_with_illegal_argument_exception() {

       Mockito.doThrow(new IllegalArgumentException("illegal"))
            .when(acmeService)
            .doSomething(Mockito.anyString());

       HttpClientResponseException responseException = Assertions.assertThrows(HttpClientResponseException.class,
            () -> client.toBlocking().exchange(HttpRequest.GET("/")));

       Assertions.assertEquals("Internal Server Error: illegal", responseException.getMessage());
   }
}
```

The problem is when the whole test class is executed, only the first test pass, the second and the third fail because no exception is thrown (I am expecting exceptions thrown). But if I execute each test separately, every test pass (exception thrown as expected).

Mocking of AcmeService isn't working correctly. I also tried to reset the mock (Mockito.reset) after each test, but this isn't working either.

I am not able to simulate exceptions thrown during service execution. Debugging shows, that in every test case the mocked service is different. The mocked service used by the hello world controller is also different (that's why it isn't working).

The mocking examples of https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-test/latest/guide/index.html show no difference.

So, my question is, how can I simulate different exceptions thrown by the service. Why isn't my test working?

I appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: try `@After public void resetMocks() {
          Mockito.reset(acmeService);
    }`

Comment: I already tried this this without any effect. The main problem is that the acmeService used by the controller is not the same as in my tests. According to the docs the controller should have a proxy that points to the mock used in the test, but this is not the case.

Comment: "According to the docs the controller should have a proxy that points to the mock used in the test, but this is not the case" How do you know that its not the case?

Comment: @JamesKleeh: Because I debugged the test. I injected the controller and compared both AcmeServices. The acmeService() method is called before each test. During the first test, both AcmeServices are the same (used by the controller and the injected one in the test). Before the second test is executed, the acmeService() method is executed again and after that the injected acmeService and the one used by the controller are different. And this explains why no exception is thrown. Seems to be a bug to me.

Comment: Was a bug and is fixed with version 1.1.3. See https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-test/issues/41